# Should we do request manipulation or network packet manipulation for SDN vulnerability analysis?

Tags: tls, web-application, network, penetration-test, vulnerability

I am planning to do vulnerability analysis of a Software Defined Network. Since the connection between the business apps and the controller of the SDN would be done over the application layer, I would assume web attacks can be explored through request manipulation in Burp Suite. Since the connection between the OpenFlow switch and the controller is over SSL, will the vulnerability analysis involve packet manipulation too?

Comment: I think the question is both too broad in scope, is missing relevant details and is confusing terms. SSL does protect against manipulation only if properly implemented (strong ciphers, proper certificate validation, certificates protected against misuse) so you have to check this. If only the server is authenticated SSL does not protect against malicious clients either, so you might need to account for this too. Also, the connection between the OpenFlow switch and the controller is also at the application layer even this is not "web". Similar "web" can involve SSL too.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume since the connection between the application and the SDN controller is over the application layer and that between the controller and the switches is over the network layer, you would require Burpsuite and Wireshark for request and packet manipulation respectively.